# .NET API array of objects becomes empty object ONLY when returned as JSON

Tags: sql, .net, json, api

I have a .NET API that was formally rendering views with a model, but is now set to return the model directly to the API caller as a JSON. When rendering the view with the model, I have an array of objects that populates fine. When returning strictly JSON data, it's missing almost all of that data.

Running the debugger, on the return the data is present, but the end result has an empty object instead of an array of objects.

Pseudo Code:

```
obj.property1 = sqlQuery1.ToArray(); //Empty object if returned using Ok(result)
obj.property2 = sqlQuery2.ToArray(); //Empty object if returned using Ok(result)
obj.property3 = sqlQuery3.ToArray(); //This one comes through for some reason

//Pack these objects into array
return Ok(result); //Most properties become {}, debugging confirms they exist at this point
return View(result); //All properties render normally
```

Comment: What type is `result`?  Is it a `JObject` or `JArray`?

Comment: `result` is a model object with numerous properties inside.

Comment: OK, can you post a [mre] to help us reproduce the issue you are seeing?

Comment: Fiddler is a good debugging tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved. The issue is that the models were using `[DataContract]` and this resulting in empty objects. Removing this safely fixed the issue.